# Unit testing a service layer

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

I'm currently working on writing unit(ish) tests for a service layer that connects to a database and makes changes. I am using MSTest, Autofac and NHibernate.  I want to make sure that I am doing this correctly.

What I want to do is:

1) Setup a database that stores some known static data.  (I think I've figured this out).

2) Test the following `GetAll()` method:

```
public class TagService
{
    private readonly ITagRepository _tagRepository;

    public TagService(ITagRepository tagRepository)
    {
        _tagRepository = tagRepository;
    }

    public IQueryable<Tag> GetAll(bool includeDeleted = false)
    {
        if (includeDeleted)
            return _tagRepository.GetAll();

        return _tagRepository.GetAll().Where(p => p.Deleted == false);
    }
}
```

In my unit test project:

I implement a static class called `BaseTest`

```
public static class BaseTest
{
    private static bool Intialized;
    public static IContainer container;

    static BaseTest()
    {
        Intialized = SetupUnitTestDatabase();
        container = BuildKernel("unittests");
    }

    private static IContainer BuildKernel(string tenantName)
    {
        var tenantIdStrategy = new StringTenantIdentificationStrategy(tenantName);

        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        //Adding the tenant ID strategy into the container so controllers
        //can display output about the current tenant.
        builder.RegisterInstance(tenantIdStrategy).As<ITenantIdentificationStrategy>();
        builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        //Register Dependencies Shared Accross Tenants
        builder.RegisterModule(new GeographyModule());
        builder.RegisterModule(new ORMModule());
        builder.RegisterModule(new EmploymentModule());
        builder.RegisterModule(new AuthenticationModule());
        builder.RegisterModule(new NotificationsModule());
        builder.RegisterModule(new NationBuilderModule());
        builder.RegisterModule(new CommonModule());
        builder.RegisterModule(new ContributionsModule());
        builder.RegisterModule(new IntakeManagementModule());
        builder.RegisterModule(new StatsModule());
        builder.RegisterModule(new MatchingModule());
        builder.RegisterModule(new ExportModule());
        builder.RegisterModule(new BlueStateDigitalModule());
        builder.RegisterModule(new RevolutionMessagingModule());
        builder.RegisterModule(new TaskSchedulerModule());

        //Create multitenant container based upon application defaults
        var mtc = new MultitenantContainer(tenantIdStrategy, builder.Build());
        //register all the tenants using helper method in auth project.
        mtc = mtc.RegisterAllTenants();

        return mtc;

    }
}
```

And for a test on the `GetAll()` method I do the following:

```
[TestClass()]
public class TagServiceTests 
{
    [TestMethod()]
    public void GetAllTest()
    {
        //arrange
        var tagService = BaseTest.container.Resolve<TagService>();
        //act
        var result = tagService.GetAll();
        //asert
        Assert.IsTrue(result.Count() == 10);
    }
 }
```

This test passes, but I'm not sure if setting tests up this way is going to cause problems.  It is important that I actually test actual database transactions because my most common errors are not in logic of the application, but rather NHibernate choking on a query, I need to make sure that this doesn't ever happen in production.

Comment: It is not clear what your question is, please be more specific.

Comment: Is it appropriate to inject the static class.